Regex issue with ifconfig
I want to parse ifconfig to get ip_address, net mask and broadcast. and these are optional fields. If it present, it should return but if not it should return None.
My below pattern works fine but if 'inet6' is preset and above 'inet' in ifconfig, then this pattern returns None. I am not sure why it is still trying to match with inet6.
ifconfig_output = """
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:1a:2b:3c:4d:5e
    inet6 fe80::1a2b:3c4d:5e6f:7g8h prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4
    inet 192.168.1.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
"""

# Regex pattern to capture MAC, IPv4 (inet), and IPv6 (inet6) addresses
pattern = re.compile(r'ether (?P<mac_address>[a-f0-9:]+).*?'
                     r'(?:\s+inet (?P<ip_address>[\d\.]+) '
                     r'netmask (?P<netmask>0x[a-f0-9]+) '                      
                     r'broadcast (?P<broadcast>[.a-f0-9:]+))?.*?')

print(pattern.search(ifconfig_output).groupdict())


A regex dot does not match newlines, by default.  The only place your current regex can match a newline is the \s+ in the "inet" part of the expression, but there's nothing that can match the newline between the "ether" and "inet6" lines (and therefore nothing even gets a chance to match the "inet6" line itself).  Specifying the re.DOTALL flag would be one solution.

uhh no. that didn't help either.

Output of ifconfig is not supposed to be machine readable. It's different between platforms.

Get network address and network mask in Python

You need to get rid of that ?, fourth character from the end of the regex.  That's making most of the expression optional - there's still an overall successful match, but most of it is being matched by an earlier .*? rather than the groups you actually want.
